# What should be the resolution of an image in React Native?

Tags: image, react-native, pixel

React Native components are unitless, and represent density-independent pixels according [this page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/height-and-width.html).

However, when I create an image, what should be its ideal resolution, in pixels? Let's say I have a tag like this:

```
<Image style={{width: 100, height: 100}} source={require('./img/myimage.png')} />
```

How big should I make my image to make sure it renders well in all devices?

Comment: Check this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42971004/2405689 It helped me a lot with responsive sizing of images & fonts.

Answer (score 1):

In react-native documentation it says that you can name your images with the suffixes @2.x and @3.x to make the images look right on every device. In your images folder, you should do something like this:

```
    .
├── button.js
└── img
    ├── check.png
    ├── check@2x.png
    └── check@3x.png
```

Also, remind to don't use other values than @2.x amd @3.x, because when you run `./gradlew bundleRelease` to build your production app, it will get an error, and it quite doesn't tell your that the problem is the suffixes that aren't recognized.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! A link to the documentation would be useful here :)

Comment: Link here : https://reactnative.dev/docs/images#static-image-resources