# Adjust font size based on screen size of smartphone React native

Tags: css, react-native, react-native-ios

Hey guys im using `const {width,height} = Dimensions.get('window');`
 to adjust my font based on screen width size.
using like this....

```
fontSize:width/24
```

its looks good in iPhone and android device like 5.5 inch device but in my Galaxy s9 it looks horrible I want to set my font based on screen which can be adjust by itself..
how can I do it

Comment: I think this library is the best option for scaling https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet

Comment: one option is to use `rem` or `em` instead of px for your font-size

Answer (score 0):

Then the best option is to use vmax and vmin units.

vmin: 1/100th of the smallest side,
vmax: 1/100th of the largest side

take a look at it [here](https://css-tricks.com/simple-little-use-case-vmin/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a responsive ilibrary like this that will handle things better.

[react-native-size-matters](https://github.com/nirsky/react-native-size-matters)

Eg:

```
import { scale, verticalScale, moderateScale } from 'react-native-size-matters';

const Component = props =>
    <View style={{
        width: scale(30),
        height: verticalScale(50),
        padding: moderateScale(5)
    }}/>;
```

Thus things will look better in all devices. Use verticalScale for defining things relative to height of the device. scale can be used for normal things .. then there is a custom option moderateScale where u can manually define the scaling ratio as well.

For more details refer : [Scaling React Native apps](https://medium.com/react-native-training/scaling-react-native-apps-for-tablets-211de8399cf1)

PS: there are other options as well where u can manually define a custom class to get the PixelRatio and everything. but this is a straight forward approach.

Refer [PixelRatio Approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628677/react-native-responsive-font-size)

Comment: how can I use this PixelRatio.get() to implement based on there screen size

Comment: something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628677/react-native-responsive-font-size

Answer (score 0):

In order to get access to the device's pixel density and font scale, you can benefit from **PixelRatio** according to the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pixelratio.html).

As indicated in the docs, [PixelRatio.get()](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pixelratio.html#get) provides you with the device pixel density:

```
var dynamic_fontSize = 20;
if(PixelRatio.get() === 1) {  // mdpi Android devices
    dynamic_fontSize = 12; 
} else if(PixelRatio.get() === 1.5) {  // hdpi Android devices
    ... 
}
else { ...
```

Another idea is to make use of the layout size using [roundToNearestPixel()](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pixelratio.html#roundtonearestpixel). 
Let's imagine you want to adjust the size of an element to take over 98% of the screen’s width in dp and 10% of the screen’s height in dp:

```
export const widthPercentageToDP = widthPercent => {
  const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
  // Convert string input to decimal number
  const elemWidth = parseFloat(widthPercent);  
  return PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(screenWidth * elemWidth / 100);
};

export const heightPercentageToDP = heightPercent => {
  const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
  // Convert string input to decimal number
  const elemHeight = parseFloat(heightPercent); 
  return PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(screenHeight * elemHeight / 100);
};
```

This thread provides you with a clear example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35074379/4687359