# Change font size in textinput react native based on screen size

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i want to change `fontSize` in `textinput` based on screen width in react native.

i want to make something like this, expected result is the `fontSize` go smaller when adding numbers to the `textInput`

[image: Demo Expected Results]

Resources i tried:

[React Native Responsive Font Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628677/react-native-responsive-font-size)

https://reactnativeexample.com/responsive-fontsize-based-on-screen-size-of-the-device-in-react-native/

and much more didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate relationship of text and container width together with letter spacing, margin etc.

`fontsize = containerWidth / Math.max(text.length, 1) - adjustment`

snack example here: https://snack.expo.io/PJeeBTGGe