# React Native Samsung One UI 3.0 Dimensions screen width not returning correct value

Tags: react-native

I'm using react native 0.63.4 and I use `<View style={{flex: 1}}>` for the root element of every page.

I use `Dimensions.get("screen").width` to make the elements responsive. For some reason the value of screen width is not correct but a larger value. Thus every element on the screen gets larger.

Expected behavior:
[Expected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJd4s.png).
Issue: [issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGhlH.png)

I've tested with many devices. I see this problem only on Galaxy S20 Ultra and S10 Lite. The issue occurred after installing the Android 11 & OneUi 3.0 update.

Code:

```
const {height: screen_height, width: screen_width} = Dimensions.get('screen');

<View style={{ flex: 1,justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center" }}>
  <Text style={{fontSize:screen_width/15}}>text</Text>
</View>;
```

What could cause the problem?

UPDATE: The issue appears only when the device's screen resolution is set to 3200x1440. The app works as expected on lower resolutions.

Comment: Can you add your code? It is pretty hard to help you without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this code:

```
const {height: screen_height, width: screen_width} = Dimensions.get('screen');
```

With this:

```
let scale = Dimensions.get('screen').scale / Dimensions.get('window').scale;
const screen_height =  Dimensions.get('window').height * scale;
const screen_width =  Dimensions.get('window').width * scale;
```

Comment: can you please explain a logical reason please. I'm a bit confused

Answer (score 0):

try `Dimensions.get("window").height` and `Dimensions.get("window").width` can resolve your case.

Answer (score 0):

I think your text components are overlapping the actual viewport. Could you add the code which renders the actual (text) content?

And if it causes the issue, then you could try to wrap it with `flexWrap: 'wrap'` style property.

Comment: The fontSize of the text element is: screen_width / 15. It works as expected on other devices, and the text fits the screen. Probably in One UI, the value of screen_width goes huge. Thus, the text size gets very large that it doesn't fit the screen anymore. I guess I'll have to find another way to make my app responsive.

Comment: Those "magic numbers" like `screen_width / 15` are usually causing problems sooner or later. I suggest you to find another way of calculating and scaling content.

Comment: Have you got any suggestions? I've made a lot of research but couldn't find anything other than using screen_width to make a responsive screen.

Comment: @bilin Have you taken `PixelRatio` in calculations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628677/react-native-responsive-font-size