# React Native Samsung S21 Ultra UI 4.0 Android 12 Dimensions screen width not returning correct value

Tags: android, react-native

I have this issue when I open the app, I select multi-window option from the android nav bar and then I select the app. I have the same issue from this related article:

[React Native Samsung One UI 3.0 Dimensions screen width not returning correct value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65485878/react-native-samsung-one-ui-3-0-dimensions-screen-width-not-returning-correct-va)

I cannot comment there. I don't have min 50 rep :(

I already have the fix from there. But is not working here.

```
let scale = Dimensions.get('screen').scale / Dimensions.get('window').scale;
const screen_height =  Dimensions.get('window').height * scale;
const screen_width =  Dimensions.get('window').width * scale;
```

I'm using react native 0.66.3 and UI 4.0

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I'm having the same issue on One UI 4.0 :/

Comment: nope. saddly :(