# How to set font-size to "larger" or 140% of system default

Tags: javascript, react-native, font-size

I want to provide to my users a possibility to display certain `<Text/>` elements with a larger font-size, than a system default. The [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text-style-props#fontsize) provides a number only for that style.

I want to display texts either with web-css "large" or "larger" values or maybe with 140% of the **original** font size.

I found couple of questions on SO and 3rd party libs, like [responsive-fontsize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-fontsize), but they all seem not relavant to me.

What's the easiest way to do what I want?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on _why_ the others don't suit your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting I figured out that the default font size - if not set and for Android at least - corresponds to **14**.

From that base one can increment the size to 18 to get roughly 140% of the original size.

Good thing is the font is scaled depending on system-wide font size.

Answer (score 1):

1. You define styles for each component, such as `<Text />` you described. Here is an [article](https://scalablecss.com/styled-components-global-styles/)
2. You can set your `fontSize` as kind of formula, example: `style={{fontSize: 10*1.4}}` or `style={{fontSize: x*1.4}}` where x is your global variable.

P.S. Normally, you can't just make font bigger in %

Answer (score 1):

You can use em for a relative size.

With em, you can say how many times bigger or smaller you want your text to be. For example:

0.5em will be half of your initial size, 1em will be the same size, 2em will be twice the size.

```
<Text style={{fontSize: `${relativeSize}em`}}>
      I am {relativeSize} times bigger than I was supposed to be
</Text>
```

Here is a working example:
https://snack.expo.io/@andrpr/bigger-text-example

If you want to use percentages, you can convert them to how much bigger you want the text to be:

```
const percentage = 140;
const relativeSize = percentage/100;
```

https://snack.expo.io/@andrpr/percentage-bigger-text-example

Comment: doesn't work on a device. Throws an exception `java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is [PixelRatio](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pixelratio) which let you more control on your fonts sizes. Or else it could help someone who reached your post.

> [PixelRatio](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pixelratio) gives you access to the device's pixel density and
> font scale.

So after you got the informations you want you can play with it.

You can find exemples on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35074379/7942242)

> For exemple :
>
> ```
> var React = require('react-native');
>
> var {StyleSheet, PixelRatio} = React;
>
> var FONT_BACK_LABEL   = 18;
>
> if (PixelRatio.get() <= 2) {
>   FONT_BACK_LABEL = 14;
> }
>
> var styles = StyleSheet.create({
>   label: {
>     fontSize: FONT_BACK_LABEL
>   }
> });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a custom `Text` component that translates the defined textSize style to the adjusted scale. The scale you can get from a Context-Provider, Redux or Recoil, etc.

something like this (untested):

```
export function MyText(props) {
  const { fontScale } = useContext(TextContext);

  return (
    <Text {...props} style={[...style, { fontSize: style.fontSize ? style.fontSize * fontScale : undefined }] />
  );
}
```