# React Native Text : Word overflows to the next line and breaks the word. How can we prevent this

Tags: ios, react-native, text, ms-word

[image]

As you can see here, the word transforming is overflowing to the next line and breaking. How can we prevent this? is there a way to reduce the font size when this happens so that the entire word appears on the same line? we are looking for iOS solutions.

Comment: there are multiple solution to this go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628677/react-native-responsive-font-size

Comment: Thanks a majority of solutions in the thread are about responsive font sizes and dont necessarily fix the word break problem. But its a good start for us. we will see which one can work for us.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

Apply

> ellipsizeMode="tail"

in your `Text`

Comment: thank you for responding.  we dont want the long words cut. we want them displayed in full on the card

Comment: have you tried the above 'ellipsizeMode = "tail" without NumberOfLines ?